# How do I access my classes from the python console on MAC OSX?

Tags: python, macos, pylons

I'm trying to access my classes via

```
from project import *
```

But from the python console something seems to be off with the paths.  How do I set the correct paths to my project so I can import classes?

My models are stored in:

```
/Users/username/project/project/model

from project import *
```

And the error reads:

```
ImportError: No module named project
```

Thanks.

Comment: here are your projects - what path?

Comment: "off"?  Do you have an error message that would reveal to us what you're seeing?

Comment: From which path do you start the console?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance.  I am new to python.  I have updated the question with the error message.  It's probably a basic solution, I'm just not sure how to tell the console where my classes are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the following choices

- Start your python session in the /User/username/project folder
- Change your import line to `from project.project import *`
- Set the PYTHONPATH environment variable to /User/username/project (`setenv PYTHONPATH /User/username/project`)
- Append /User/username/project to [sys.path](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path)

`import sys`

`sys.path.append('/User/username/project')`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you will have to set the PYTHONPATH env variable, or change in the correct directory.

I assume you do not start your console from: /Users/username/project

You have several options now:

1. Change to that directory
2. Set the PYTHONPATH env variable to that directory (however that is done in MacOSX)
3. Use the `site` module to add the path: [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html#site.addsitedir)

Answer (score 1):

This might be a silly suggestion, but do you have a `__init__.py` file in the module you're importing? if not, then create an empty one. You're also going to need to run `from project import *` from the `/Users/name/project/` directory. ie: you'll need to start the python CLI from `/Users/name/project/`. If that isnt suitable thenas already suggested you can change where python looks for modules.

As a sidenote, using `from module import *` is commonly seen as bad form. Try to specify what you want imported.